# Graphing T1 using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying IBM's code for graphing T1 and I keep getting the following error:

```
ibmqfactory.load_account:WARNING:2020-05-28 12:28:57,538: Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced.
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/util.py:109: DeprecationWarning: The QuantumCircuit.iden() method is deprecated as of 0.14.0, and will be removed no earlier than 3 months after that release date. You should use the QuantumCircuit.i() method instead.
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The link to the code is here: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/guide/wwwq/decoherence

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, there are two messages here and they are both just warnings.

The first `Credentials are already in use` error means that you have called `load_account()` when you already had an account loaded.

The second message, `DeprecationWarning`, is letting you know that a method that you are using will be removed in a future version of Qiskit and so it is best to move code over to using a different method. In this case, it means that you need to used `.i()` instead of `.iden()`